# ASP.NET Core project Won't login after publishing project to IIS in local system

Tags: asp.net

I have created an asp.net core project and it works really fine if I run it on debug mode; however I have just tried to publish the application on my local machine and run it from the IIS server, the application will run, but if I try to login it won't work?!

I really couldn't figure out where the issue comes from

Comment: Please post any logs or stacktrace if you need help.

Comment: 2020-11-03 09:23:41 ::1 POST /Account/Login - 5001 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/86.0.4240.111+Safari/537.36+Edg/86.0.622.58 http://localhost:5001/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F 200 0 0 936

Comment: here is what i get in the log file

Comment: What do you mean "won't work"? Are there any other errors at responed page?

Comment: i have programmed the login to respond back if login cardinalities are not correct, but it doesn't show anything, it just reload back to the login page

Comment: I don't get wherer it doesn't show anything or it shows login page.
Anyway, is there any difference between debug environment and published environment.
Computer, network, or database the application will connect?